# Driving with parking brake on

Tags: honda, odyssey, parking-brake

I am a inexperienced driver. 
Yesterday, I drove my car, Honda odyssey, for total 4 miles by 30-40 mph with parking brake on. Even though brake light was on, I didn't notice it. 
I felt vibration and heard noise. 
What would happen to my car?

Comment: Hi Inji, can you tell us the year of your Odyssey?  Also, have you noticed anything different when you brake after the incident compared to before?  For example, do you find yourself having to press the brake pedal a little harder or when you brake, does it feel spongy instead of stiff now?  Or any other differences at all?  At that speed, it's unlikely to cause impactful damage, but it's still possible at that distance.  Sometimes the pads get a little glazed, but that usually works itself out.

Comment: I appreciate for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 miles at 30/40 mph could heat the brake components and wheel hub until the brake fluid boils, the wheel bearing grease runs out, the rotors/drums warp, etc. I recommend complete disassembly and inspection including repack wheel bearings and bleed brake fluid.

Comment: I appreciate for your advice.

Comment: Machanic said that my car needs to change front pads without any comment about wheel bearing and blooding brake fluid. Can it happen?

Comment: Machanic said that rear pads also needs to be changed but it was already worn out but the change of front pads was due to this damage.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with the brake arrangement on your car but the parking brake usually locks the rear wheels.